# Probability that any specific coin has Head when $3$ distinct coins are tossed?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Consider a small problem of tossing 3 ordered and distinct coins ($C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$). The sample space is

$$ \{ \mbox{HHH}, \mbox{HTH}, \mbox{HHT}, \mbox{HTT}, \mbox{THH}, \mbox{THT}, \mbox{TTH}, \mbox{TTT} \} $$

so probability of choosing any event from this sample space is $\frac18$ (assuming uniformly distributed). Now what I intend to compute is given the sample space, the probability that any specific coin has $H$, i.e., $C_1 = H$ (or $C_2 = H$ or $C_3 = H$) is $\frac48 = 0.5$ (evident by observation of the sample space, but how to put it down mathematically?).  Also is there any method to prove that events $C_1 = H$, $C_2 = H$ and $C_3 = H$ are independent of each other?

To elaborate, can I form 3 random variables for $C1$, $C2$ and $C3$ such that $R_{C1}=0$ if $C1=T$ and $R_{C1}=1$ if $C1=H$ (similarly for other coins) with uniform distribution. Then create a random variable representing the outcomes of sample space $R_{sample space}$. Then for an event say $HHT$ prove that $P(R_{sample space}=HHT)=P(R_{C1}=H)*P(R_{C2}=H)*P(R_{C3}=T)$ for independence?

Thanks.

Comment: Independence is an *assumption* here.  a priori there could be  some force or agency forcing the coins to match or not.  But it is generally assumed that distinct coins are independent of each other (and that the toss of a given coin is independent of all other tosses of that coin).

Comment: Similarly for your other question...I'd have thought you were *assuming* that each coin came up $H$ with probability $\frac 12$.  It's not something you can prove abstractly.

Comment: No, I do not want to assume they are independent, but prove it. Can it be infered that Probablity(any event from sample space) = P(C1) P(C2) P(C3). Hence they are independent?

Comment: To stress: the mere fact that the sample space has exactly $8$ events in no way shows that the probability of each is $\frac 18$. That value follows from the standard assumptions, but one could make different assumptions.  Like maybe $C_1$ has $H$ on both sides.

Comment: What assumptions do you want to start with?  If you have no assumptions, you can't deduce anything.

Comment: Uniform distribution of the events of sample space

Comment: Well, if the *only* experiment you are allowing is to throw all three then I don't think you can deduce much.  But...that seems very unusual.  Aren't you also assuming uniformity for *any* combination of tosses?    Otherwise, well, I can imagine contrived examples where the distribution changes if you are only throwing two of them (say).

Comment: Usually the way we conclude that the distribution is uniform is to assume that the coins are fair and independent. You can assume the distribution is uniform and work out that the coins are fair and independent in this case, but in general it is a bad assumption to simply assume that a given set of results has uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ be three indicator random variables,

$$C_i =\begin{cases} 1, \textrm{ if coin $i$ is Head} \\ 0, \textrm{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Then
$$P(C_1 = 1 \cap C_2 = 1 \cap C_3 = 1 )=1/8$$
and the same holds for any other combination.

To see that, note that

\begin{align}
P(C_1 = 1 \cap C_2 = 1 \cap C_3 = 1 )&=P(C_1 = 1 | C_2 = 1 \cap C_3 = 1 )P(C_2 = 1 \cap C_3 = 1 )\\
&=P(C_1 = 1 | C_2 = 1 \cap C_3 = 1 )P(C_2 = 1 | C_3 = 1 )P(C_3=1)\\
&=1/2 \cdot 1/2 \cdot 1/2
\end{align}
where you can check the above equation by simply counting the number of events wherein the condition corresponding to the probability holds, divided by the number of events in the sample space.

Therefore, this implies that if the 8 possibilities are equally likely, the three coins are independent and identically distributed.

Reciprocally, if the the three coins are i.i.d. and unbiased, all 8 possibilities are equally likely.

Therefore, the 8 possibilities are equally likely if and only if the 3 coins are unbiased and i.i.d.